# Android 11: Create *package name* folder in Android/data by default?

Tags: android, directory

Im trying to create a specific folder in /Android/data/*package name*/ from C++. Im using mkdirs for that. Not a big surprise it crashes the whole app because it doesnt have an access to Android/data (that means app cannot create it's own app folder). If i create *package name* folder by myself, then i can easily create folders and/or files inside it.

How can i do this? Am i missing something?

FIXED: Thanks @blackapps for a hint with getExternalFilesDir! You're lifesaver!

Comment: Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception. Start to repair that before you implement a solution.

Comment: `/Android/data/` Dat is not a possible full path. Please tell full path as you have to use that in your code too.

Comment: `that means app cannot create it's own app folder` Indeed. But it will be created as soon as you call getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: I will try to use getExternalFilesDir, thanks for that hint!

Comment: I think this is obvious that i mean /sdcard/Android/data. Thanks again, i will try to use that!